# how to set target printer in PrinterJob in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, printing

I have a situation that need to print order bill in cash counter and packing area(warehouse ).

Technically, how to print `javafx.print.PrinterJob` by saying printer name.

1) Sample print

```
public static void PrintSample() {
    Label lbl = new Label("This is sample \n\n\n\n\n\nprint");
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null  ) {

        boolean success = job.printPage(lbl);
        if (success) {
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
}
```

2) Get list of printers

```
public static void GetListOfPrinters() {
    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    System.out.println("Number of print services: " + printServices.length);

    for (PrintService printer : printServices) {
        System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method 'createPrinterJob' with no-args creates a printer job for the default printer. You can use the other version of the method 'createPrinterJob(Printer printer)' to create a printer job for the specified printer.
First get instance of printer like below:

```
Printer myPrinter;
ObservableSet<Printer> printers = Printer.getAllPrinters();
for(Printer printer : printers){
    if(printer.getName().matches("spefic printer name")){
        myPrinter = printer;
    }
}
```

Now Create a printer job for 'myPrinter' like this:

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(myPrinter);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is too late but any one need the answer for the same question:
you can use this class to print file(not node)....

```
public static void print(String imageName, PagesManager pagesManager) {
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
    PageLayout pageLayout
            = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
    PrinterAttributes attr = printer.getPrinterAttributes();
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job.showPrintDialog(pagesManager.getScene().getWindow())) {
        String selectedPrinter = job.getPrinter().getName();

        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        pras.add(new Copies(1));
        PrintService pss[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, pras);
        if (pss.length == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No printer services available.");
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < pss.length; i++) {
            if (pss[i].getName().equals(selectedPrinter)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        PrintService ps = pss[i];
        System.out.println("Printing to " + ps);
        DocPrintJob docPrintJob = ps.createPrintJob();

        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(imageName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, null);
        try {
            docPrintJob.print(doc, pras);
        } catch (PrintException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        try {
            fin.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(myPrinter); 
this line is not working give error The method createPrinterJob(Printer) is undefined for the type PrinterJob

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html It seems that the method exists. Maybe you have not imported the class correctly. If you got any doubts, please add a comment. Your text is not an answer to this question.